# Submit form on element other than input type=submit

Tags: form-submit

I would like to submit a form by clicking an element other than a submit button, in this case a

. I thought I could do it this way but the form does not submit on the click event but will submit when I click the submit button.

HTML

Submit

JQ
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
$('p').click(function() {
$('form').submit(function(data) {  
    alert($(this).serialize()); // check to show that all form data is being submitted
    $.post("serializearray.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){
        alert(data); //post check to show that the mysql string is the same as submit                        
    });
    return false; // return false to stop the page submitting. 
});
});
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').submit(function(data) {  
    alert($(this).serialize()); // check to show that all form data is being submitted
    $.post("serializearray.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){
        alert(data); //post check to show that the mysql string is the same as submit                        
    });
    return false; // return false to stop the page submitting. 
  });

  $('p').click(function() {
    $('form').submit();
  });

});
```

When you pass a function to `$('form').submit(function(){})` method you are binding a callback so it won't execute. So bind the callback and then inside the click handler call submit simply like `$('form').submit()` which will trigger a submit on the form

Answer (score 0):

On the click event you setup the handler on submit event, but you actually don't submit the form. Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {  
    alert($(this).serialize()); // check to show that all form data is being submitted
    $.post("serializearray.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){
        alert(data); //post check to show that the mysql string is the same as submit                        
    });
    return false; // return false to stop the page submitting. 
});
$('p').click(function() {
    $('form').submit();
});
```